# new buttons appear automatically on google maps(Android) when click on marker?How to remove?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps in my android application as map provider .

I have noticed that google maps now show two small buttons(bottom right) automatically when the user click on a custom marker on the screen.

they take you to google maps ( one to main screen and the other to navigation )

how to disable these buttons ? because they interfere with application design

a screenshot of the new buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing is called [Map Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_toolbar). You can disable it by calling  [UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)):

```
GoogleMap map;
....... //init map

map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

those u need to disable...Something like these

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```